# Where can I find the best and worst performing US stocks on a given date?

Tags: equities

I'm interested in researching the effects of a stock ranking at extremes on a certain date, and was wondering if anyone can help me find a tool/site which allows to easily retrieve the best/worst performing stock on a given (historical) date. I'm interested in US stocks and the performance criteria should be % change.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Quant Stack Exchange, for starters you should expand on your criteria for performance. Also, what markets are you interested in will any suffice ?

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in US markets. Criteria for performance is % change (daily).

Comment: You should update your question with those details, otherwise it will likely be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

This links shows the S&P500 stocks. You can sort them by clicking on the column "change": http://www.barchart.com/stocks/sp500.php

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to see those stocks in a given historical date.

Comment: If you are interested in historical results, then you have to define the set of stocks you are sampling from carefully. For example are you interested in S&P 500 stocks? Then you must use a database which accurately keeps track of changes to the S&P membership over time. Enron was once in S&P 500, but isn't now, you get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

**Quickest way** : Have a look at Bloomberg `EQS` (*Equity Screening*) function:

1 - Type `EQS` and hit `GO`.

2 - Add criteria under section, `Screening Criteria`; select More Options to view all screening criteria. Hoping you find or define your *Performance criteria* there;

3 - Click `Results` located in right corner of screen.

4 - Click `Output` to save to Excel, PDF or print.

**Alternatively** : Resort to `FREE Quandl API` to query a list of your specified data over a defined time period. This could be done in putting all the data into a `financial time series object` in Matlab for instance, compute the return on those data and use `min()` or `max()` to retrieve the best/worst performing asset.

PS: It takes a little bit more time to program than using Bloomberg `EQS` function, but it also worth doing it.

Let's know if you need further assistance on this.

Best,